# What is the proper way to put divider lines between navigation links?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS/HTML homework assignment to make a page look like the page my instructor gave me. I need to add "pipes" in between the links. I added pipe characters to my HTML, but I don't feel like that is the proper way to do it. Thanks! Here is a screenshot of what it needs to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKYUq.png

Comment: There is no "proper" way. you can do it in any way you please as long as it's maintainable and easy to understand by others, like possible teammates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe characters work, but you could do the same thing with some CSS.

If your markup is like this:

```
<nav>
  <a href="/about.html">About</a>
  <a href="/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

You can add some CSS to style the "right side" of each link element to have a border, except for the last element because you don't want a floating divider line on the end of the links.

```
nav > a {
  border-right: solid 1px #eff0f1;
}
nav > a:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

This will add a border to the right side of all your nav links, but then overrides the final nav link to not have a right border.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to add a **border-right** to your nav items. This can all be done with CSS and no text, like with the pipe "|". Just need to ensure that the last nav item does not have the border-right. See the example below, cheers.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* This is the important piece */
li:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```